# Ring with a set of vectors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to define the '*' operation in the ring with a set of vectors in $R^3$ with usual vector addition as a '+' operation so it forms a ring with unity? Find in this ring nilpotent elements and Zero divisors.

Comment: This question is a bit too vague to be answered well. There is one obvious way to do this that works for all fields and all dimensions, but there are also other ways, depending...

Comment: I see, sorry. I've edited that it is in $R^3$ dimension. However, i'd like to know the obvious way) I tried the cross product, but it doesn't have a unity.

Comment: You didn't try coordinatewise multiplication?

Comment: Ok. You can try $$(x_1,y_1,z_1)*(x_2,y_2,z_2)=(x_1x_2,y_1y_2,z_1z_2)$$ as suggested by rschwieb (and what I referred to as the obvious way). You can also try
$$(x_1,y_1,z_1)*(x_2,y_2,z_2)=(x_1x_2,x_1y_2+x_2y_1,x_1z_2+y_1y_2+z_1x_2)$$ if you want a different ring and different unity, nilpotent elements/zero divisors.